# Efficient implementation of data batch reader function in tensorflow-r1.0

Tags: python, file, io, tensorflow, queue

I am implementing a NMT model for the wmt-14 data set, which has more than 12,000,000 lines. I convert it to binary format which is suitable for tf. And I use the [`data_batcher.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/textsum/batch_reader.py) by `tensorflow/models` for reading the data. But when I call `NextBatch` function, it hang at this line of code:

```
buckets = self._bucket_input_queue.get()
```

The related code are as below:

```
class Batcher(object):
  """Batch reader with shuffling and bucketing support."""

  def __init__(self, data_path, vocab, hps,
               article_key, abstract_key, max_article_sentences,
               max_abstract_sentences, bucketing=True, truncate_input=False):
    """Batcher constructor.

    Args:
      data_path: tf.Example filepattern.
      vocab: Vocabulary.
      hps: Seq2SeqAttention model hyperparameters.
      article_key: article feature key in tf.Example.
      abstract_key: abstract feature key in tf.Example.
      max_article_sentences: Max number of sentences used from article.
      max_abstract_sentences: Max number of sentences used from abstract.
      bucketing: Whether bucket articles of similar length into the same batch.
      truncate_input: Whether to truncate input that is too long. Alternative is
        to discard such examples.
    """
    self._data_path = data_path
    self._vocab = vocab
    self._hps = hps
    self._article_key = article_key
    self._abstract_key = abstract_key
    self._max_article_sentences = max_article_sentences
    self._max_abstract_sentences = max_abstract_sentences
    self._bucketing = bucketing
    self._truncate_input = truncate_input
    self._input_queue = Queue.Queue(QUEUE_NUM_BATCH * self._hps.batch_size)
    self._bucket_input_queue = Queue.Queue(QUEUE_NUM_BATCH)
    self._input_threads = []
    for _ in xrange(16):
      self._input_threads.append(Thread(target=self._FillInputQueue))
      self._input_threads[-1].daemon = True
      self._input_threads[-1].start()
    self._bucketing_threads = []
    for _ in xrange(4):
      self._bucketing_threads.append(Thread(target=self._FillBucketInputQueue))
      self._bucketing_threads[-1].daemon = True
      self._bucketing_threads[-1].start()

    self._watch_thread = Thread(target=self._WatchThreads)
    self._watch_thread.daemon = True
    self._watch_thread.start()

  def NextBatch(self, drop_prob):
    """Returns a batch of inputs for seq2seq attention model.

    Returns:
      enc_batch: A batch of encoder inputs [batch_size, hps.enc_timestamps].
      dec_batch: A batch of decoder inputs [batch_size, hps.dec_timestamps].
      target_batch: A batch of targets [batch_size, hps.dec_timestamps].
      enc_input_len: encoder input lengths of the batch.
      dec_input_len: decoder input lengths of the batch.
      loss_weights: weights for loss function, 1 if not padded, 0 if padded.
      origin_articles: original article words.
      origin_abstracts: original abstract words.
    """
    enc_batch = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size, self._hps.enc_timesteps), dtype=np.int32)
    enc_input_lens = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
    dec_batch = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size, self._hps.dec_timesteps), dtype=np.int32)
    dec_dropped_batch = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size, self._hps.dec_timesteps), dtype=np.int32)
    dec_output_lens = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
    target_batch = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size, self._hps.dec_timesteps), dtype=np.int32)
    loss_weights = np.zeros(
        (self._hps.batch_size, self._hps.dec_timesteps), dtype=np.float32)
    origin_articles = ['None'] * self._hps.batch_size
    origin_abstracts = ['None'] * self._hps.batch_size

    buckets = self._bucket_input_queue.get()
    for i in xrange(self._hps.batch_size):
      (enc_inputs, dec_inputs, targets, enc_input_len, dec_output_len,
       article, abstract) = buckets[i]
      drop_idx = np.random.choice(dec_output_len, int(drop_prob*dec_output_len))

      origin_articles[i] = article
      origin_abstracts[i] = abstract
      enc_input_lens[i] = enc_input_len
      dec_output_lens[i] = dec_output_len
      enc_batch[i, :] = enc_inputs[:]
      dec_dropped_batch[i, :] = dec_batch[i, :] = dec_inputs[:]
      dec_dropped_batch[i, drop_idx] = self.unknown_id 
      target_batch[i, :] = targets[:]
      for j in xrange(dec_output_len):
        loss_weights[i][j] = 1
    return (enc_batch, dec_batch, dec_dropped_batch, target_batch, enc_input_lens, dec_output_lens,
            loss_weights, origin_articles, origin_abstracts)

  def _FillBucketInputQueue(self):
      """Fill bucketed batches into the bucket_input_queue."""
      while True:
        inputs = []
        for _ in xrange(self._hps.batch_size * BUCKET_CACHE_BATCH):
          inputs.append(self._input_queue.get())
        if self._bucketing:
          inputs = sorted(inputs, key=lambda inp: inp.enc_len)

        batches = []
        for i in xrange(0, len(inputs), self._hps.batch_size):
          batches.append(inputs[i:i+self._hps.batch_size])
        shuffle(batches)
        for b in batches:
          self._bucket_input_queue.put(b)
```

I wonder why the elements in the `_bucket_input_queue` can not get properly? And how should I adjust it? Thanks a lot in advance!